# JQuery List Events

Tags: javascript, jquery

At the moment I'm building a list using the following code:

```
$('<li id="li' + jJob.Id + '"><div style="width: 98%; background-color: #9E7BFF; colour: #000000"><a href="javascript:void(0);">' + jJob.Type + ' ' + jJob.AddressClean + ' (' + jJob.Status + ')' + '</a></div></li>').click(function(e) { ShowStatus('job ' + jJob.Id + ' is available'); UnassignJob(jJob.Id); $(this).remove(); }).bind("contextmenu", function(e) { alert('li' + jJob.Id); return false; }).appendTo('#assignmentList');
```

This works as previously required.  However I need to be able to add another a link which will show another menu allowing various options.  The problem is that I've attached the click event to the div.  How can I attach it only to the a link?

- Create li
- Create div
- Create a link with click event
- Create another a link click event
- Append li to #assignmentList

Mark

Comment: I know my comment is not altogether constructive, but my first reaction to this was: gosh, I wonder who gets to maintain and debug this stuff later. And then, I started thinking about jQuery templates...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to append your `onclick` event to your `<a>` link inside the `li` correct?

One option would be to remove the

```
.click(function(e) { ShowStatus('job ' + jJob.Id + ' is available'); UnassignJob(jJob.Id); $(this).remove(); })
```

And instead place this in your link, e.g.

```
'<a href="javascript:NewClickEvent(' + jJob.Id + ')"> stuff </a>'
```

Where NewClickEvent is defined as

```
function NewClickEvent(jobID)
{
ShowStatus('job ' + jobID + ' is available'); 
UnassignJob(jobID); $(this).remove();
}
```

Note- you may have to fiddle this a bit to get `$(this)` to work as it did previously... not sure what object it will bring back currently.

You could use either the href attribute as shown, or add an `onclick` attribute to the link.

Hopefully this should give you at least some inspiration :)

Comment: Dykam, thanks for the reply - it turned out that the $(this).remove() was redundant!

Comment: No problem - the answer is mine, Dykam kindly corrected a typo :) 

Another thing thing to note is that moving things to functions like this may improve the readability of your code too.

Comment: Zeus, sorry for the confusion! My coding style can be difficult to read - like to get everything in one line - but that has bitten me a few times!